# How to call function in all children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is what I tried. The docs seem to say that `this.props.children` is a special property managed by React but `children` is undefined in this example. What am I doing wrong?

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', {}, this.props.content);
  }     
  someFunc() {
    log("child", this.props.content);
  }
}
           
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', {ref: 'self'}, 
      React.createElement(Child, {content: "child A"}, null),
      React.createElement(Child, {content: "child B"}, null),
      React.createElement(Child, {content: "child C"}, null)
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("children:", this.props.children);      
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {
      log("child");
      child.someFunc();
    });
  }
}
            
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("react"));

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(" ");
  document.getElementById("log").appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

The specific issue I'm trying to solve is I have Windows Explorer like interface with group names on the left and a list of all items of all groups on the right. When I click on a group name on the left I want to scroll the list on the right to the corresponding items. Note there is no internal connection between the groups on the left and the items on the right. They are just 2 representations of the same data. In order to do what I want to do, when an element is clicked on the left I was hoping to find the element on the right and ask the DOM where it is so I can set the scroll offset. I have enough info to find the element on the right but when I tried to iterate over them using `this.props.children` I found it's undefined.

Note in my actual code I'm not running this code in `componentDidMount`, the code gets called in response to a mouse click

---

so my first workaround, pass in an EventEmitter to all children, then emit an event. Could just as easy be a `registerYourselfWithParent` function passed in in props but that would you'd also need a `unregisterYourselfWithParent`. I guess 6 of 1, 1/2 dozen of another

Comment: You can't access the children of your component through `this.props.children`. `this.props.children` designates the children being passed onto you by the parent, not the ones you created in `render()`. In other words, rendering `ReactDOM.render(<Parent><Child content="TEST"></Parent>, document.getElementById("react"));` will log the children with content `"TEST"`

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically assign refs to your child components like `React.createElement(Child, {content: "child A", ref:getRef()}, null),` where getRef is a function as

```
var getRef = function(){ return 'Child-'+(refi++); }
```

and then loop over the refs using `Object.keys(this.refs).forEach()`

```
componentDidMount() {

    Object.keys(this.refs).forEach( (child) => {
      if(child !== 'self') {
      console.log(child);
      this.refs[child].someFunc();
       }
    });
  }
```

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', {}, this.props.content);
  }     
  someFunc() {
    console.log("child", this.props.content);
  }
}
           
class Parent extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    var getRef = function(){ return 'Child-'+(refi++); },    refi=0;
   
    return React.createElement('div', {ref: 'self'}, 
      React.createElement(Child, {content: "child A", ref:getRef()}, null),
      React.createElement(Child, {content: "child B", ref: getRef()}, null),
      React.createElement(Child, {content: "child C", ref:getRef()}, null)
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
          
    Object.keys(this.refs).forEach( (child) => {
      if(child !== 'self') {
      console.log(child);
      this.refs[child].someFunc();
       }
    });
  }
}
            
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("react"));

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(" ");
  document.getElementById("log").appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

I hope it helps your cause